# Apache server default pahe how do i change? (WINDOWS)

Tags: apache, testing

Im running a apache server and when they connect to the normal addres they gets to this [image: yeah]

But i dont want the to get to that page so if some could explain to me how i change or maybe link a guide/youtube guide i would be grateful

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folder you're searching for is in the inside the xampp folder you created during installation.

```
[XAMPP FOLDER]/htdocs
```